# coroutine scope and async - right approach?

Tags: kotlin, jvm, kotlin-coroutines

I love the concept of co-routines and I've been using in my android projects. Currently i'm working on a JVM module which i'll be including in a Ktor project and i know ktor has support for co-routines.

(find the attached code snippet)

Just wanted to know is this the right approach? 
How do i use async with recursion?

Any resources that you can recommend which can help me grasp more in-depth knowledge of co-routines would be helpful.

Thanks in advance!

```
override suspend fun processInstruction(args.. ): List<Any> = coroutineScope {

 val dataWithFields = async{       
     listOfFields.fold(mutableList()){ acc,field ->
    val data = someProcess(field)
    val nested = processInstruction(...nestedField) // nested call

    acc.addAll(data)
    acc.addAll(nested)
    acc
}
}

return@coroutineScope postProcessData(dataWithFields.await())

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to process all nested calls in parallel, you should wrap each of them in `async` (`async` should be inside of the loop). And then, after the loop, you should `await` all the results. (In your code you run `await` right after single `async`, so there is no parallel execution).

For example, if you have `Element`:

```
interface Element {
    val subElements: List<Element>
    suspend fun calculateData(): SomeData
}

interface SomeData
```

And you want to `calculateData` of all `subElements` in parallel, you can do it like this:

```
suspend fun Element.calculateAllData(): List<SomeData> = coroutineScope {
    val data = async { calculateData() }
    val subData = subElements.map { sub -> async { sub.calculateAllData() } }
    return@coroutineScope listOf(data.await()) + subData.awaitAll().flatten()
}
```

---

As you said in a comments section, you need parent-data to calculate sub-data, therefore the first thing `calculateAllData()` should do is calculate the parent-data:

```
suspend fun Element.calculateAllData(
    parentData: SomeData = defaultParentData()
): List<SomeData> = coroutineScope {
    val data = calculateData(parentData)
    val subData = subElements.map { sub -> async { sub.calculateAllData(data) } }
    return@coroutineScope listOf(data) + subData.awaitAll().flatten()
}
```

---

Now you may wonder how fast it works. Consider the following `Element` implementation:

```
class ElementImpl(override val subElements: List<Element>) : Element {
    override suspend fun calculateData(parentData: SomeData): SomeData {
        delay(1000)
        return SomeData()
    }
}

fun elmOf(vararg elements: Element) = ElementImpl(listOf(*elements))
```

And the following test:

```
println(measureTime {
    elmOf(
        elmOf(),
        elmOf(
            elmOf(),
            elmOf(
                elmOf(),
                elmOf(),
                elmOf()
            )
        ),
        elmOf(
            elmOf(),
            elmOf()
        ),
        elmOf()
    ).calculateAllData()
})
```

If parent-data isn't needed to calculate sub-data, it prints `1.06s`, since in this case, all the data is calculated in parallel. Otherwise, it prints `4.15s`, since elements tree height is 4.

Comment: That was quite helpful. if sub data is dependent on data (means we need parent element information to process sub element) then i should call await right after declaring val data = async { calculateData() } and as you pointed out there will be no parallel execution. What would be an efficient way to deal in that case??

Comment: @TechDrago never call `await` right after `async`. It's pointless. Just remove `async` from `val data = async { calculateData() }` and `await` from `data.await()`.

Comment: @TechDrago if you do what I've said in a previous comment each element own data will be calculated before sub-elements data. But then sub-elements data will still be calculated in parallel because of `awaitAll`.

Comment: Hey @Bananon what if SomeData Returned a value from parents calculation  i have to feed that value to calculateData (on Subelement). So i cannot say result.myvalue because its a deferred object 
Something like this:
```async { calculateData("Hardcoded value") }```


```subElements.map { sub -> async { sub.calculateAllData("Value from Parent's Operation (Network operation suppose)") } }```

Comment: Thank you, your answer helped me to understand the concept better.